# How do you get Selenium to work with SmartGWT components?

Tags: gwt, selenium, smartgwt, selenium-ide

I'm trying to use Selenium to select a row in a SmartGWT table.

I have tried the following commands to no avail (the click definitely happens but the table widget doesn't respond):

```
    selenium.mouseDownAt("isc_ContactListGrid_0_wrapper", "50,50");
    selenium.clickAt("isc_ContactListGrid_0_wrapper", "50,50");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install SmartGWT user extensions and use specific SmartGWT locator (scLocator)

See more here - http://www.rhq-project.org/display/RHQ/Testing+SmartGWT+with+Selenium